# Uploading and Downloading File using spring hibernate,little confuse about the approach.can anybody guide me on the same...?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-security

I am creating one module in which i need to provide functionality for upload and download any file through browser.

I tried searching for the approaches to accomplish my requirements.

DB server : Oracle 10 g
framework : Spring & Hibernate
Front End : JSP

Now i have two options

1. Importing file into oracle(data type blob) database and retrieving same file using BufferedOutputStream
2. I'll create folder on server for storing all files . User will upload there images on that location. database will have one column to store absolute path of that file which will be use while reading that file

eg User uploads imageABC.jpg , application will upload that file(with updated name unique_id.jpeg) under directory D:\DIS21\Storage\
in database path column will be updated by D:\DIS21\Storage\unique_id.jpeg

while reading the file application will read file under path D:\DIS21\Storage\

i am little confuse about the approach and security aspects. can anybody guide me on the same..??

Comment: but if suppose there are thousands of file to be uploaded then will it work ??

Comment: sorry, after reading your second option again, I see that I have understoud it completly wrong.

Comment: what is wrong in second option? I think it should work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches work. The downside with option 1 is that it will put extra I/O pressure on the database, but depending on the load on your system, that may not be an issue.

The main problem with option 2 is that it prevents horizontal scaling, i.e. you won't be able to add additional servers if your usage increases without moving all files onto a network file share of some sort. Again, this adds network and I/O overhead but may or may not be a problem.

I've built numerous sites that stores files in databases and as long as you apply good data design (primarily you should split blobs out into their own tables) you should be fine.

Comment: Thnaks pap....but  what do you mean by "primarily you should split blobs out into their own tables" and what do you mean by "Good data design" Thnaks in advance.\

Comment: So, say you have a table for files. It might have a column that is the name of the file and a description and whatever else you want to store with it. What you should avoid is having the BLOB column that is the content in the "main" table. Instead, create a FILE_CONTENT table that only has an id that is a foreign key to the main table, and a BLOB that is the content.

Comment: I dont think your answer is correct. Its no problem to have the blob column aside of other columns. Otherwise please explain in detail why you think this is the case.